# SmsManger.getDefault(); cannot be resolved error

Tags: android

There is an error in my code like `SmsManger.getDefault(); cannot be resolved` error

```
  Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1); 
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("Send Sms", null);
                    String phone="0899786592";
                    String message="Rescue Me: /n I am at Lattitude- "+lat+" ,Long- "+lon;
                    SmsManager smsManager =new SmsManager.getDefault()
//getting error in the above line i also tried without type casting.. works but the smsManager is getting an error
                    try{
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone,null,message, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sms Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sms not sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `getDefault ` is `static` method so not need to access it by creating object of `SmsManager ` just use  `SmsManager smsManager =SmsManager.getDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate `SmsManager`, it is a Singleton and has a private constructor. That's why you are getting an error with `new SmsManager.getDefault()`.

To get an instance, you just need to call the static method : `getDefault`.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
```